# How to test with Jest a fetch() call result

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm very new to Jest and I need to test a class method that fetches data. It's a regular JS file, I'm not on node environment.

In my `script.js` I have the following class:

```js
class Manager {
  constructor(params) {
    // ...
  }
  
  async getData() {
    const data = await fetch(this.#requestUrl)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => data)
    return data
  }
}

module.exports = {Manager}
```

In runtime it works, I do receive data from the URL in the following format: `{id: 'some_id', list: [{}, {}, ...]}`. However now I need to test it.

So first I wrote this test in my `script.test.js`:

```js
const { Manager } = require('./script')

describe('Manager Script', ()=> {
  const manager = new Manager({//params})

  test('Successfully fetching data', () => {
    expect.assertions(1)
    return manager.getData().then(({ data }) => {
      expect(data.list.length).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(6)
    })
  })
})
```

I received the following error: `ReferenceError: fetch is not defined`

I tried to mark the test callback function as async and tried this:

```js
const data = await manager.getData().then(res => res)
expect(data.list.length).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(6)
```

Same result - `fetch is not defined`

So I tried to install `jest-fetch-mock` and mock the result. After many attempts this mock worked for me:

```js
require('jest-fetch-mock').enableMocks()

// in suit
beforeEach(() => {
  fetch.resetMocks()
})

//in the actual test
fetch.mockResponseOnce(
  JSON.stringify({
    data: {
      id: 'abc',
      list: [{ id: '1' }, { id: '2' }, { id: '3' }, { id: '4' }, { id: '5' }, { id: '6' }],
    },
  })
)

manager.getData().then(({ data }) => {
  expect(data.list.length).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(6)
})
```

But the question remains - how do I test the actual call? The data that I should receive from `getData` method?

I saw a few similar questions here on SO, but I couldn't find a solution for my case.

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55498693/how-to-really-call-fetch-in-jest-test

Comment: @evolutionxbox I saw this one too, not sure if it will work, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Seems wrong to be actually testing the actual call. Why is the api not have its own tests to verify that it is working correctly? Front end should not care about testing the back end. Front end tests should say if I get this, does it do that.

Comment: what's the point of testing in the frontend that the backend provides the data you expect? The frontend isn't in control of that. Your backend code should do the tests that it gives the correct data, while in the frontend you can simply mock the data and test your JS code does the right thing with it. [EDIT: basically what @epascarello said, I was just a bit slower and more long-winded! :-) ]

Comment: @epascarello Well, these are valid points, haven't thought about that. As I said - I'm very new to Jest (well, and writing test in general). So basically I can assume that the mock I've written above should be sufficient for me, correct? Especially considering it returns data in the exact same structure the API does. But what would happen if the API introduces some breaking changes?

Comment: @RobinZigmond Well, basically the same comment as in the reply to epascarello above :)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Well, maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it didn't work for me. In my class I exposed a method to get a request URL. Then in the test I tried `const reqUrl = manager.requestUrl; const data = await fetch(reqUrl).then(res => res.json()).then(({ data }) => data); expect(data.list.length).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(6)` and I received the following error: `FetchError: invalid json response body at  reason: Unexpected end of JSON input`